# Passing Gatsby Image As Prop

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, gatsby-image

I'm trying to learn Gatsby by building a demo blog. I have an Archive component, where I'm querying blog data, and I'm trying to pass the Image down as a prop, however, when im trying to access the prop within my Article component, I keep getting a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'childImageSharp' of null`.

Here is my code:

```
import React from "react"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"
import Img from "gatsby-image"

// components
import Article from "./article"

const BLOG_QUERY = graphql`
  {
    allMarkdownRemark {
      nodes {
        excerpt
        frontmatter {
          title
          date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
          author
          slug
          image {
            childImageSharp {
              fluid(maxWidth: 600) {
                ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp_tracedSVG
              }
            }
          }
        }
        timeToRead
      }
    }
  }
`
const Archive = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(BLOG_QUERY)
  console.log(data)
  return (
    <div>
      {data.allMarkdownRemark.nodes.map(node => (
        <Article
          key={node.frontmatter.slug}
          title={node.frontmatter.title}
          excerpt={node.excerpt}
          image={node.frontmatter.image.childImageSharp.fluid}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Archive
```

Markdown header as below:

```
---
slug: "/what-is-gatsby"
title: "What Is Gatsby?"
image: "../images/gatsby.png"
author: "Joshua Isaac"
date: "2019-10-23"
---
```

Data logged:
[image]

Article Components:

```
import { React } from 'react'
import Img from 'gatsby-image'

const Article = (props) => {
 return(
  <div>
    <h3>{props.frontmatter.title}</h3>
    <Img fluid={props.image} />
  </div>

 )
}
```

Comment: The code is fine, please elaborate the image location, and make a producible example [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: images are in "/src/images" folder. i defined image paths within markdown file

Comment: so show us, show us the markdown, please read the link I shared

Comment: Also, show us the data value you logged

Comment: Ive updated my question @dennisVash

Comment: Please show your logged data, did you check your query in GraphiQL?

Comment: How many markdown files are there? Do all of them have a `frontmatter.image`?

Comment: @DennisVash ive attached a picture of my logged data

Comment: @ksav, there are 4 images, each contains an image

Comment: Please don't post images, post the code, also you showed only the first node, there are 4.

Comment: Try showing the `Article` component, maybe you don't access it as expected

Comment: Ive included my Article component and how im attemping to access the prop in my question, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that each of your markdown files has an `image` property in the frontmatter that contains a relative path to an image.

Also, in `<Article/>` it looks like you are trying to access a non-existant property: `props.frontmatter.title`.

You only pass `key, title, excerpt & image` props to `<Article/>`, and so the prop `frontmatter` simply does not exist.

```
// article.js

import { React } from 'react'
import Img from 'gatsby-image'

const Article = (props) => {
 return(
  <div>
    <h3>{props.title}</h3>
    <Img fluid={props.image} />
  </div>
 )
}
```

Comment: The title is also part of the frontmatter, how am i able to access the title but not image if they are both within frontmatter?

Comment: sorry @ksav, im a bit consufed, could you elaborate? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be useful to someone:

1. Install `npm install --save gatsby-source-filesystem`
2. Add to your gatsby-config.js:

```
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `static`,
        path: `${__dirname}/static/blog/`,
      },
    },
```

3. Create a folder **static** next to src
4. Change the path to your image in the markdown file
5. And than:

```
import React from "react"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"

// components
import Article from "./article"

const BLOG_QUERY = graphql`
  {
    allMarkdownRemark {
      nodes {
        excerpt
        frontmatter {
          title
          date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
          author
          slug
          image {
            childImageSharp {
               gatsbyImageData(
                 formats: [AUTO, WEBP, AVIF]
               )
            }
          }
        }
        timeToRead
      }
    }
  }
`
const Archive = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(BLOG_QUERY)
  console.log(data)
  return (
    <div>
      {data.allMarkdownRemark.nodes.map(node => (
        <Article
          key={node.frontmatter.slug}
          title={node.frontmatter.title}
          excerpt={node.excerpt}
          image={node.frontmatter.image}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Archive
```

```
import { React } from 'react'
import { GatsbyImage, getImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"

const Article = (props) => {

const image = getImage(props.image)

 return(
  <div>
    <h3>{props.title}</h3>
    <GatsbyImage image={image} alt={props.title} />
  </div>

 )
}
```

5. If it doesn't work: `gatsby clean`